# ClassNotFoundException: sun.net.www.MimeTable when migrating to JBoss 7.1.1

Tags: java, jboss, classnotfoundexception

I m getting following error when deploying ear file in Jboss 7

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.net.www.MimeTable from [Module "deployment.XXX.ear.XXX.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
        ... 43 more
```

Can you please suggest me any solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding following line to **JBoss home**\modules\sun\jdk\main\module.xml

```
 <dependencies>
      <system export="true">
         <paths>
           ..


           <path name="sun/net/www" />
        </paths>
```

Answer (score 0):

Non-API packages from the JRE are not exported by default by the JBoss modules environment.

See [Class Loading in AS7](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/Class+Loading+in+AS7), section *Accessing JDK classes*, for a solution.